# How to find first key "id" on the page in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I would like to find the first `id` of the `index` of the first `ng-repeat` on the page.  without jQuery and use this value and store inside a new `$scope.firstId`. I need the value in the view.

**EDIT : I need this value to play the first id found on the page.**

I have three $scope in my controller :

```
$scope.albums = {}
$scope.artists = {}
$scope.tracks = {}
```

All these elements have a key `id`

```
<div ng-repeat="album in albums">
   {{ album.id }}
</div>
<div ng-repeat="artist in artists">
   {{ artist.id }} 
</div>
<div ng-repeat="track in tracks">
   {{ track.id }} 
</div>
```

From there, I would like to get the first key `id`, in this case it will be the **first value of albums**. In the same way, if I change the order as below, I would like the **first value of artists**.

```
<div ng-repeat="artist in artists">
   {{ artist.id }} 
</div>
<div ng-repeat="track in tracks">
   {{ track.id }} 
</div>    
<div ng-repeat="album in albums">
   {{ album.id }}
</div>
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do, why do you need this ? Why don't you just pick the first "artist" if you now that in your HTML your starting with artists...? Don't you just need to do that with CSS :first-child selector ?

Comment: That is precisely what I want to do that, because it doesn't always start with "artist".

Comment: still not clear, why do you need the "id" for ? Depending on your answer, there a re several possibilities

Comment: how do you want to change order of yours repeters ?

Comment: I need the value in the view ! (edit)

Comment: try using `ng-init` on the first div with `ng-repeat`

Comment: Aren't you simply looking for `{{artists[0].id}}`?

Comment: @CodeHater yes, `ng-init` and then ?

Comment: Can you check my update please ?

Comment: `ng-init="firstId = artists[0].id"`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do so :

**Without refactor :**

Just check in controller if album/artist/track is empty and take the first non-empty object to retrieve its ID

**With refactor and using `ng-repeat` `$first` attribute:**

```
$scope.data = [
    {
        type: "albums",
        items: []
    },
    {
        type: "artists",
        items: [
            {
                id:1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: "tracks",
        items: []
    }
]


<div ng-repeat="dataType in data">
    {{dataType.type}}
    <div ng-repeat="item in dataType.items">
        {{ item.id }}
        <span ng-show="$parent.$first && $first">I am the first item!</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ng-init directive to evaluate an expression, You could create a function to evaluate and pass $first and the id then in the function you could capture the id value and store it in a scope variable.

The docs show using the nginit with an ngRepeat

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit